# Modifying Yii Portlet Layout

Tags: yii

Is it possible to modify the layout of a Yii Portlet?

Within my application I want to use a Portlet to allow for users to admin certain controllers and the Portlet with htmlOptions seems like a perfect fit but I'd like to change the layout/view it uses.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlOptions` let you add some options to the container tag.

This widget is not using view.

If you want to modify the presentation of the title, then you should override the method `renderDecoration()`. Its default code is:

```
protected function renderDecoration() 
{ 
    if($this->title!==null) 
    { 
        echo "<div class=\"{$this->decorationCssClass}\">\n"; 
        echo "<div class=\"{$this->titleCssClass}\">{$this->title}</div>\n"; 
        echo "</div>\n"; 
    } 
}
```

To customize the style you can change `contentCssClass`, `decorationCssClass` and `titleCssClass`

Then to change the content of the Portlet you have to override the method `renderContent()` that is empty by default. You can also set the content as follow:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet'); ?>
    ...insert content here...
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```